# How to get a patent or patent application permalink at the JPO website?

Tags: patent-search, databases

This is clearly the Japan version of [How to get a patent or patent application permalink at the USPTO website?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/3304/how-to-get-a-patent-or-patent-application-permalink-at-the-uspto-website), so I steal from there:

> I'd like to link to certain patents <s>or patent applications</s> filed with the <s>USPTO</s> JPO.
>
> Is there a <s>simpler</s> way to link to applications and granted patents at the <s>USPTO</s> JPO?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How good is your Japanese? This method only works using the Japanese portal for J-PlatPat. The English one omits the key link.

1. Search for the patent using [J-PlatPat](https://www.j-platpat.inpit.go.jp/web/tokujitsu/tkbs/TKBS_GM101_Top.action). The three important fields are 特許出願番号 (for patent application numbers), 
   公開・公表特許公報（A） (for publication numbers) and 特許公報・公告特許広報（B） (for patent numbers).
2. Click on the publication or registration number (as the case may be).
3. Click on the URLコピー button. This will cause a pop up to display a URL for that patent/application.

If you wanted a link to an English site, you could try Espacenet.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks to Google Translate my Japanese is good enough, and I would trust the recipient of the link to be able to use that, too :) I had had the same idea before, but I started out at [this link](https://www.j-platpat.inpit.go.jp/web/all/top/BTmTopPage), where the patent cannot be found. In addition, Google Translate breaks the forms, so thanks for your individual steps :)

Comment: Just a note, that copied URL returns not the patent, but a search result page showing only that patent. But this may be good enough if there's nothing besser.

Comment: Final comment: as the English website offers only a non-binding English translation of all patent information, I see no advantage of using that over Google Translate. So generating a link as you describe and then forming a Translate link will be perfect.